# Can't preventDefault() on drop event on a div with Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I'm trying to implement a file dropper on a `<div>` as a Svelte component. I've tried every combination of `preventDefault` but the browser still loads the dropped file instead of passing it to the component.

```
<script>
    function handleDrop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("onDrop");
    }

    function handleDragover(event) {
        console.log("dragOver");
    }
</script>

<style>
    .dropzone {
        display: block;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #555;
    }
</style>

<div class="dropzone" on:drop|preventDefault={handleDrop} 
    on:dragover|once|preventDefault={handleDragover}></div>
```

I've tried with and without `event.preventDefault();` in handler functions. Also tried with `on:dragenter` event and different combinations of modifiers, i.e. with `stopPropagation`. The browser still opens the dropped file. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**(UPDATE) FIX:**
Okay, the culprit was the `|once` modifier. Once removed from the `on:dragover` in `<div>` everything works great, except that `dragover` event fires continuously while dragging across the div. `event.preventDefault();` inside handler functions is not needed as the `|preventDefault` modifier works correctly. Here is the code (omitting `<style>` for brevity):

```
<script>
    function handleDrop(event) {
        console.log("onDrop");
    }
    function handleDragover(event) {
        console.log("onDragOver");
    }
</script>

<div class="dropzone" on:drop|preventDefault={handleDrop} 
    on:dragover|preventDefault={handleDragover}></div>
```

Not submitting this as an answer yet, because I would like to find out why I can't use `|once` modifier for `dragover` event, which would be useful for my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Problem:**

This is a common gotcha rooted in HTML drag-and-drop (not Svelte's fault), where the last `dragover` event must be canceled in order to cancel `drop`. Looking at Svelte's [once](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/80ef6f190de79abba60152e6176c78caf076d087/src/runtime/internal/utils.ts#L84) directive, it's just a closure that runs your handler one time. However, dragover will fire multiple times before being dropped, so the immediately preceding dragover is not prevented.

**Solution:**

Just include the directive without a handler:

```
<div 
   on:dragover|preventDefault
   on:drop|preventDefault={handler} 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .dropzone {
        display: block;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #555;
    }
</style>
```

---

```
<div class="dropzone" on:drop={event => handleDrop(event)}
    on:dragover={handleDragover}>
</div>
```

---

```
<script>
    export function handleDragover (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log("dragOver");
    }

    export function handleDrop (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log("onDrop");
    }
</script>
```

Look here: https://svelte.dev/repl/3721cbc9490a4c51b07068944a36a40d?version=3.4.2

https://v2.svelte.dev/repl?version=2.9.10&gist=8a9b145a738530b20d0c3ba138512289

Comment: This still doesn't work on my end. Moreover, `export function` now creates warnings in the console: `<FileChooser> was created without expected prop 'handleDrop'`

Comment: According to [this tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/dom-events) I should be able to just add `on:drop={handleDrop}` and in the function I would receive the event object anyway: `function handleDrop(event)`. And that works with the `dragover` event: while dragging across the `div` I can see the event object in the console if I do `console.log(event)`.